# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage does not release memeory after sending

Tags: c#-4.0, smtpclient, mailmessage

I'm developing an EmailService to read the new mails of Emails table(Sql). This is a Windows Service written in C# and .NET 4.0. Every email record has a size of mail body measured is about 12kb...after sending every an email my service calls MailMessage.Disposed() method and set SmtpClient to null. But the memory of my Service keeps increasing and not back to the started Service (takes about 7mb system memory) even no new email is read. It often consumses 70mb - 120mb system memory and this is so weird :(

Do you have any solution to decrease the memory for my case above?

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: Are you sure that problem isn't elsewhere? Comment out the code that sends the messages and see if it still leaks.  Or, better yet, use a memroy profiler.

Comment: I have been using ANTS memory profiler to tracking the memory and notice that the 'cause of memory increasing is about the MailMessage did not dispose...when I did not call the sendMail method. I assumpted to read new 100000 mails and everything were fine. So, I bet the MailMessage is a problem

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, where system resources were not actually released until the .exe was closed (back in the 2.0 days with some windows forms programming).

Comment: That's not a useful answer, especially since WinForms has nothing to do with System.Net.Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `using` for the `SmtpClient` and the `MailMessage` objects:

```
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("ipaddress")){
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage()){

//Do something to fill the message...

client.Send(message);

}

}
```